# multiuser authentification in laravel with one users table and linked roles table

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am currently working on my very first laravel (and programming at all) project, and I have a problem: I'm unable to create multi-user login and registration form where all users will be stored in one single database table(users), and will have role_id parameter of roles table. The roles are super-admin, admin and user

I created project, and two database tables as follows:

users

```
$table->increments('id'); 
$table->string('name'); 
$table->string('email')->unique(); 
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned(); 
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles'); 
$table->string('password'); 
$table->rememberToken(); 
$table->timestamps();
```

roles

```
$table->increments('id'); 
$table->string('role');
```

And in tables model I have defined the relationship (user - has one id from roles table and role has many users)

I also

```
run php artisan make:auth
```

Can anyone help me with suggestions?!
Grateful

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Edit your question, and post the code there, not in a comment.

Comment: thanks for suggestions! :)